# Unable to extract password hash from database with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

**EDIT:** To clarify, I am unable to extract the hashed password from my database using prepared statements.

I'm trying to create a login system that uses prepared statements, password_hash and password_verify.

I have created the registering form that creates the user, with the hashed password using `password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

This works properly.

However, I am now stuck on creating the login form.

I am trying to get the password hash that gets stored when a user registers but I cannot get it to work with prepared statements.

This is what I currently have.

```
<?php
require('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_password FROM `users` WHERE user_name = ?');

  if($stmt) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

    $stmt->execute();

  }
}

?>
```

How do I use the data that I got from the select query? And how do I use it to verify the password?

I tried:

```
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($loginUsername, $hash);
```

That only stored the username, but not the password hash and I have no clue why.

Verifying the password would use this?
`password_verify($password, $hash);`

**UPDATE**

```
<?php
require('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_password FROM `users` WHERE user_name = ?');

  if($stmt) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

    $stmt->execute();

    // Get query results
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    // Fetch the query results in a row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $hash = $row['user_password'];
      $username = $row['user_name'];
    }

    // Verify user's password $password being input and $hash being the stored hash
    if(password_verify($password, $hash)) {
      // Password is correct
    } else {
      // Password is incorrect
    }

  }
}

?>
```

Comment: So then your *actual* question is why your query doesn't work and really has nothing to do with `password_verify()` at all?

Comment: @Sammitch That is the main issue, correct. I have also barely used these functions before, so I am unsure whether I am using them correctly or not.

Comment: Do you do some sort of `fetch()` to actually get hold of a result row anywhere

Comment: @RiggsFolly So do I need to use something along the lines of `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Something like that except you dont have a `$result` look at the manual page. or try `$stmt->fetch()` to fill the variables you told it to in yoru `bind_result()`

Comment: You could read the manual if all else fails, start with the [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) page and there is a useful example in there

Comment: @RiggsFolly I edited the question, this seems to work, I can echo `$hash` and see the hash that is stored in my DB. Could you please look at it and tell me if this is an appropriate way to do it?

Comment: OK you have some data, now you need to run `password_verify()` to know if the user entered the correct pasword

Comment: @RiggsFolly Edited it again. Is that correct?

Comment: It is if it works?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I just tested it and it works. Thank you a ton for helping me out.

Comment: And the good thing is you did most of it yourself

Comment: Use if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { /* Rest of code goes here */ } as it's a much better (afaik much more secure) way of determining if the form has been submitted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [PHP MANUAL](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php).Try this:

```
 <?php
    require('db.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_password FROM `users` WHERE user_name = ?');

      if($stmt) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

        $stmt->execute();

        // Get query results
        $stmt->bind_result($user_name,$hash);
        $stmt->store_result();

        // Fetch the query results in a row
        $stmt->fetch();

        // Verify user's password $password being input and $hash being the stored hash
        if(password_verify($password, $hash)) {
          // Password is correct
        } else {
          // Password is incorrect
        }

      }
    }

    ?>
```

This is how I created my login system:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,"SELECT user_email,user_password,user_firstname,user_lastname,user_role,username FROM users WHERE user_email=?");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        confirmQuery($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$user_email,$user_password,$user_firstname,$user_lastname,$user_role,$username);
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 0)
            relocate("../index.php?auth_error=l1");
        else{
            if(password_verify($password,$user_password)){
                $_SESSION['userid'] = $user_email;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                $_SESSION['firstname'] = $user_firstname;
                $_SESSION['lastname'] = $user_lastname;
                $_SESSION['role'] = $user_role;
                if(isset($_POST['stay-logged-in']))
                    setcookie("userid", $email, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                relocate("../index.php?auth_success=1");
            }else
                relocate("../index.php?auth_error=l2");
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```